# how to use "find" to search "_id => OBjectID("id")" in Perl API

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have to find a kind of "_id" in my Mongo, I can do it using the Mongo shell, and I can not do that using Perl API.

I'm trying to do it (mongo shell):

```
./mongo
use my_db
db.my_collection.find({_id : ObjectId("4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000")})
```

It works!(returns), but I can't do that using Perl API,

```
$mongo->my_db->my_collection(find({_id => "ObjectId(4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000"}));
```

Does not work because "ObjectId" is not a string, but if you do,

```
./mongo
use my_db
db.my_collection.find({_id : "ObjectId(4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000)"})
```

Does not work too, I'm guess Perl API are doing it ^

Now, I have to know how I do it:

```
db.my_collection.find({_id : ObjectId("4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000")})
```

using Perl API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation seems changed.

```
$mongo->my_db->my_collection(
  find({ _id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000")})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, you have to do:

```
$mongo->my_db->my_collection(find({ _id => $mongo->oid("4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000")}));
```

Answer (score -2):

In reading the MongoDB::Tutorial

> use MongoDB loads most of the packages you'll need to interact with MongoDB: MongoDB::Connection, MongoDB::Database, MongoDB::Collection, and MongoDB::Cursor. To use special Mongo data types (see MongoDB::DataTypes), you have to include them separately. So, usually, to use Mongo, you'll start with at least:

```
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;
```

Then you can just do this in your code:

```
$db->$collection->find_one({ _id => $id })
```